# Selenium webdriver dependeny on JQGrid ids

Tags: jqgrid, webdriver

I am using JQGrid for one of my pages. Thanks for the plugin, works like a charm.

I am writing acceptance tests on the UI using Webdriver and I need to verify data that is displayed in the grid.

My tests are dependant on the following

1. Finds the rows to be matched by row id, I specify the id values and I match by that. I hope this should be safe and should not change, please validate.
2. To look for specific cells, I am looking for td with attribute of aria-describedby with value 'list_'

I want to know if this is safe to use, or want recommendations.

Regards,

Sudhir.